# Angular DatePicker overlapping with the bootstrap modal window

Tags: css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to render a angular datepicker in the bootstrap's modal window. However the calendar is getting clipped.

Attached is the screenshot for the same.

[image]

I tried to fix it with z-index. However failed very badly.

Pre-Conditions :

1. The header and footer of the modal are fixed.
2. Only modal -body will scroll.
3. The modal-body will have max-height to occupy the remaining height of the browser
4. The content in the modal may increase or decrease. Hence the modal will extend to utilize the remaining browser height with the scrollbar only for the content.

Comment: kindly share your code..

Comment: Hi Amit, I tried to.However I could not get the entire code. Please note that I have only control over the CSS. I can manage to get the classnames to be changed. Tried to get it through fiddle. Please have a look

https://jsfiddle.net/shridharbaddur/j4eypfpy/2/

Comment: From your JSFiddle it seems you are not using [Angular UI Bootstrap module](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Is it true? Why not? In my example below I use that module which simplifies Bootstrap integration in Angular projects.

Answer (score 0):

As `<uib-datepicker>` has a fixed size and cannot be resized, you can customize the size of the small buttons (days).

For example define `.custom-size .btn-sm` CSS rule:

```
.custom-size .btn-sm {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

and then apply the `custom-size` class to uib-datepicker:

```
<uib-datepicker ng-model="dateTo" starting-day="1" min-date="dateFrom" show-weeks="false" class="custom-size"></uib-datepicker>
```

Comment: Hi beaver, thanks for you solution. However the pop over had a overflow. Hence it was getting scrollbars. I removed the overflow and it worked like magic.